# Optimization problems in non-linear and linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, dynamical-systems

I am looking for references on the implementation of computational optimization methods within the context of differential equations.

As an example, let's say I have several coupled non-linear ordinary differential equations describing a biogeochemical system where some living organism $X$ eats chemical compounds $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ that contain some energy for living and reproduction ($\Omega_1$, $\Omega_2$ and $\Omega_3$). This energy is variable in time and depends on the concentrations of $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$:

$$\begin{aligned}
  \dot c_1 &= - X \cdot c_1 \cdot \alpha\\
  \dot c_2 &= - X \cdot c_2 \cdot \beta \\
  \dot c_3 &= - X \cdot c_3 \cdot \gamma\\
  \dot X   &= \Omega_1 (c_1, c_2 ,c_3)\cdot X \cdot c_1 \cdot \alpha + \Omega_2(c_1, c_2 ,c_3)\cdot X \cdot c_2 \cdot \beta + \Omega_3(c_1, c_2 ,c_3)\cdot X \cdot c_3 \cdot \gamma
\end{aligned}$$

where

$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$$

At every timestep, an optimization algorithm finds the maximum

$$\max \bigg( \Omega_1 (c_1)\cdot X \cdot c_1 \cdot \alpha + \Omega_2(c_2)\cdot X \cdot c_2 \cdot \beta + \Omega_3(c_3)\cdot X \cdot c_3 \cdot \gamma \bigg)$$

i.e., to find the best value of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ to ensure maximum growth of $X$.

The problem I am facing is that the solution is not smooth, i.e., on some time step living organism picks best energy-yielding product $c_1$, but the next time step it picks $c_2$, so it produces non-smooth solutions for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and it kind of jumps back and forth between $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ in time, which is not very realistic. So I need some kind of optimization algorithms that has smooth switching functions, e.g., sigmoid functions, but for multiple variables $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$.

This is a toy example. In the real example, I am solving PDE of nonlinear equations and have more than $30$ variables of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$.

I found some information about receding horizon algorithm for the system that is very close to the system I described above ([link](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Use-of-Receding-Horizon-Optimal-Control-3-to-Solve-Vallino-Algar/fff0ec973e83ca34f4c504c651b1a09855c534bc)). However, the description is very general and no information on the implementation.

Comment: What can you tell about functions $\Omega_i$?

Comment: Are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ parameters or time-varying control inputs?

Comment: $\Omega$ is the function of $c$. Something like $\Omega = A + RT ln (c_1^m)/(c_2^n)$

Comment: In the question, there are functions $\Omega_1, \Omega_2, \Omega_3$, each depending on a single input, namely, $c_1, c_2, c_3$, respectively. Yet, your function $\Omega$ (where is it used?) contains two inputs.

Comment: For example, $\Omega_1$ will have $c_1$ for sure, but It may also have other $c_i$. In the real example, it is Gibbs Free Energy, $G = G_0 + RT ln A^mB^n/C^jD^k$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are the concentrations in the chemical reaction $A$ + $B$ -> $C$  + $D$ and $G_0$, R and T are  constants. In other words $\Omega = f(c_1, c_n)$

Comment: This is getting confusing. I see no $\Omega$ and no $c_4$ in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92968/discussion-between-igor-markelov-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I will assume that $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants. You can simplify your problem by eliminating $c_2$ and $c_3$ by dividing the first and second and the first and the third differential equation.

$$\dfrac{dc_1}{dc_2}=\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\dfrac{c_1}{c_2}\implies \dfrac{dc_1}{c_1}=\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\dfrac{dc_2}{c_2}$$
$$\implies \ln c_1 -\ln c_1(t=0)=\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}[\ln c_2 -\ln c_2(t=0)]$$
Now, solve for $c_2$ to obtain

$$c_2=c_2(0)\left[\frac{c_1}{c_1(0)} \right]^{\beta/\alpha}.$$

Do the same procedure for the first and third equation. If the parameters are not constant then you will have to solve a time-variant system. Then you will only be left with a second order system. You should be able to use a similar method for the resulting system.